# Java: method for an equation relevant to the Karplus-Strong equation does not return the anticipated result; unclear cause

Tags: java, equation, guitar

In Part 1 of a prompt, I am expected to integrate an equation into Java to get the value for a period (T). The equation is as follows: T = FS / (440 * (2 ^(h/12))

NOTE:

FS = sample rate, which is 44100 / 1.

h = halfstep, which is provided by the user.

An example of this equation is: 44100 / (440 * (2 ^(2/12)) = 89.3

The code I wrote is as follows:

```
public static double getPeriod(int halfstep) {
    double T = 100; // TODO: Update this based on note
    
    double FS = 44100 / 1;
    double power = Math.pow(2, (halfstep / 12));
    double denominator = 440 * (power);
    double result = (FS) / (denominator);
    T = Math.round(result);
    
    return T;
}

// Equation test.
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("halfstep is: ");
    int halfstep = in.nextInt();
    
    double period = getPeriod(halfstep);
    System.out.print("Period: " + period + " ");
}
```

But when I run through this code with h = 2, T = 100.0 instead of the anticipated 89.3 and I am not sure what the issue is. Any thoughts on what's going on?

Answer (score 0):

Because `halfStep` is an `int`, when you write

```
(halfstep / 12)
```

the calculation is done by taking `halfStep / 12` and rounding down to the nearest integer. As a result, if you plug in 2 here, then `halfStep / 12` will come back as 0 instead of 1/6. That's messing up the computation and is likely what's giving you the wrong answer.

You have a few options for how to proceed here. One would be to change `halfStep` to be a `double` rather than an `int`. Another would be to rewrite the division as

```
halfStep / 12.0
```

which, since `12.0` is a `double` literal, will perform the division in the way you intend.

One other potential issue - you declare the variable `T` as `100.0`, but never use `T` anywhere in the calculation and ultimately overwrite it before returning it. I'm not sure whether this is intentional or whether that indicates that one of the formulas is incorrect.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Changing 12 to 12.0 fixed the issue. Thank you!